# Организация like и dislike системы

Tags: ajax, php

Делаю систему лайков и дислаков для сайта, ниже вы можете увидеть код, не знаю насколько он правильный, по этому и обращаюсь к вам, есть какие замечания или идеи? или предложите более эффективное решение! Буду рад любым предложениям.

```
//проверяем голосовал ли пользователь
                    $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM vote_post WHERE post_id = '".$_POST['post_id']."' AND user_id = '".$user->id."'") or die ('Error #3887282');
                    if (mysql_num_rows($sql)){
                        echo 'вы уже голосовали';
                    }else {
                        if ($_POST['like'] == '+'){
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote_post (user_id,post_id,vote) VALUES ('$user->id','$post_id','1')") or die ('Error #76372');
                        }elseif($_POST['like'] == '-'){
                            mysql_query("INSERT INTO vote_post (user_id,post_id,vote) VALUES ('$user->id','$post_id','0')") or die ('Error #76372');
                        } else {
                            echo 'нуу я **** его знает';
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: нецензурные слова писать не нада

Answer (score 2):

А почему ели сделали `dislike` - то просто ставим 0, по мне так нужно поставить -1 , то есть если было 5 стало 4 - или я неправильно вас понимаю?

А еще у вас я так смотрю не предусмотрена следующая логика - сначала юзер поставил + , а потом он передумал и поставил - , либо просто кнопочкой ошибся - то судя по вашему коду -он уже не сможет исправить свой голос. Или вам это не нужно?

Да кстати мне кажется что вам можно вообще обойтись одним запросом

```
"INSERT INTO vote_post (user_id,post_id,vote) VALUES ('$user->id','$post_id','$like')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vote='$like'"
```

только чтоб он работал нужно сделать уникальный индекс из двух полей `user_id` и `post_id`, и перед этим привести `$_POST['like']` к `$like = 1` или -1 (у вас в логике 0)

Comment: >>а почему ели сделали dislike..
@Ale_x, он пишет инфу по каждому юзеру, а не общее кол-во лайков на элемент (счётчик)

Comment: а как потом тогда общее кол-во считается?

Answer (score 2):

1. `$_POST['post_id']` - обязательно фильтр на спец.символы и т.п. - иначе sql-инъект Вам обеспечен.
2. Не выбирайте все поля, запрос получается тяжелый, Вам это не нужно. Вот самый быстрый вариант проверки записи в бд:

   SELECT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table1 WHERE ...)

**UPD**. Как заметил [[@Ale_x](/users/3785/ale_x)](/users/3785/ale_x), если юзер ошибся, то он уже не сможет отменить действие по условию, т.к. запись же существует, а значит голосовал. Поэтому в условии проверяйте что у него там стоит.

Comment: у меня id поста проверяется регуляркой if(preg_match('/^\d+$/',$_POST['post_id'])